# Creating objects with Guava from property files

Tags: java, collections, properties, guava

In our applications we are using property files very much. Since a few months I have started to learn Guava and I liked it a lot actually.

What is the best way to create a `Map<String, Datasource>` ?

The property file format is not strict. It can be changed if It can be expressed better with another format?

Sample property file:

```
datasource1.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.11.46/db1
datasource1.password=password
datasource1.user=root
datasource2.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.11.45/db2
datasource2.password=password
datasource2.user=root
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properties class is a subclass of HashTable, which in turn implements Map.

You load it as usual with:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) { 
}
```

edit: Ok so you want to transform it to Map<String, Datasource> ;)

```
//First convert properties to Map<String, String>
Map<String, String> m = Maps.fromProperties(properties);

//Sort them so that password < url < user for each datasource and dataSource1.* < dataSource2.*. In your case default string ordering is ok so we can take a normal treemap
Map<String, String> sorted = Maps.newTreeMap();
sorted.putAll(m);

//Create Multimap<String, List<String>> mapping datasourcename->[password,url, user ]

    Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> propToList = new Function<String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Map.Entry<String, String> entry) {
            return entry.getKey().split("\\.")[0];
        }
    };

Multimap<Integer, String> nameToParamMap = Multimaps.index(m.entrySet(), propToList);

//Convert it to map
Map<String, Collection<String>> mm = nameToParamMap.asMap();

//Transform it to Map<String, Datasource>
Map<String, Datasource> mSD = Maps.transformEntries(mm, new EntryTransformer<String, Collection<String>, DataSource>() {
         public DataSource transformEntry(String key, Collection<String> value) {
            // Create your datasource. You know by now that Collection<String> is actually a list so you can assume elements are in order: [password, url, user]
            return new Datasource(.....)
         }
       };

//Copy transformed map so it's no longer a view
Map<String, Datasource> finalMap = Maps.newHashMap(mSD);
```

There's probably an easier way, but this should work :)

Still you're better off with json or xml. You can also load properties of different datasources from different files.

edit2: with less guava, more java:

```
//Sort them so that password < url < user for each datasource and dataSource1.* < dataSource2.*. In your case default string ordering is ok so we can take a normal SortedSet
SortedSet <String> sorted = new SortedSet<String>();
sorted.putAll(m.keySet);

//Divide keys into lists of 3
Iterable<List<String>> keyLists = Iterables.partition(sorted.keySet(), 3);


Map<String, Datasource> m = new HashMap<String, Datasource>();
for (keyList : keyLists) {
    //Contains datasourcex.password, datasroucex.url, datasourcex.user
    String[] params = keyList.toArray(new String[keyList.size()]);
    String password = properties.get(params[0]);
    String url = properties.get(params[1]);
    String user = properties.get(params[2]);
    m.put(params[0].split("\\.")[0], new DataSource(....)
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this but after this what are you suggesting to create Map<String, Datasource>

Comment: you can save a couple of lines in my solution. I left them so it's more readable.

Comment: I voted up :) But I would like to wait a little more. Thanks :) By the way sorry for the unclear of the question at the first time. Stackoverflow ignored it :)

Comment: No problem. I added a cleaner solution.

Comment: You should close the `FileInputStream` that is used to load the properties.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest thing is probably to use JSON rather than a properties file for this:

```
{
  "datasources": [
    {
      "name": "datasource1",
      "url": "jdbc:mysql://192.168.11.46/db1",
      "user": "root",
      "password": "password"
    },
    {
      "name": "datasource2",
      "url": "jdbc:mysql://192.168.11.46/db2",
      "user": "root",
      "password": "password"
    }  
  ]
}
```

Then you can just use a library such as [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert that into objects:

```
public class DataSources {
  private List<DataSourceInfo> dataSources;

  public Map<String, DataSource> getDataSources() {
    // create the map
  }
}

public class DataSourceInfo {
  private String name;
  private String url;
  private String user;
  private String password;

  // constructor, getters
}
```

Then to get the map:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, DataSource> dataSources = gson.fromJson(/* file or stream here */,
    DataSources.class).getDataSources();
```

Comment: I voted up because of the idea and elegant solution and also I will probably use the solution what you are suggested but in order to fit answer of the question I choose another. :) By the way Colin, I am big fan of you also. :) Thanks for your contributions. However I would also wanted to see your another wonderful implementation in order to learn better. ;)

Comment: @Sessizlik I guess my point here is to use the right tool for the job. What you have here is some structured data you want to read in. Properties files are flat and don't express the structure well. Guava doesn't change that fact. Gson (Google's JSON conversion library, incidentally) seems more appropriate and it makes this downright easy.

Answer (score 0):

If the file that you are using for configuration is not strict, you could use an XML file to store the defintion.

Example definition:

```
<resources>
 <configuration>
   <datasrouce>
     <connection name="" url="" password="" user=""/>
     <connection name="" url="" password="" user=""/>
   </datasource>
 </configuration>
</resources>
```

The using a Connection manager class you could just read the XML to obtain connection info and create an instance of connections and mange them.